# MUI DataGrid filling remaining vertical space without overflowing

Tags: css, material-ui, flexbox, mui-x-data-grid

I'm trying to get a MUI DataGrid working in a Flexbox, so that it will exactly fill the remaining space. Specifically, something like this:

```
---------------------------
| Header                  |
---------------------------
| Table Header           ^|
| Row                    ||
| Row                    ⌄|
|            Total Rows: 9|
---------------------------
| Fixed Footer            |
---------------------------
```

The problem is, I want it so that the footer is always at the bottom of the window, and the DataGrid is exactly in the space between the header and footer *no matter how many rows*.

I've managed to hack something together that works if the number of rows are less than the available space, but as soon as the number of rows exceeds the amount of space then the flexbox allows the table to just expand as needed, off the bottom of the screen.

I can also get it to work if I give the element containing the DataGrid a fixed height - then I get a scrolling table and all is good. But that requires me to start computing the correct height for the element every time the window resizes.

Is there any way to get this to work without anything like this?

Note: I'm in no way wedded to Flexbox. It just seemed like the correct way to get something to fill the remaining space. If there's a better option I'll do that :)

Cheers

Comment: Do the header and footer have a fixed height? or do their heights potentially change (e.g. due to word-wrapping) as you resize the window?

Comment: The header could be made fixed if necessary, though I'd rather not need to put in fixed heights if it can be avoided. The footer will be a few lines of text that can wrap if the window is resized sufficiently.

Comment: In that case, I'm not aware of any notably better way to handle it than computing the height of the parent element on resize and orientation-change events by getting the height of the header and footer and then setting the data grid parent element height to `calc(100vh - ${headerAndFooterHeight}px)`.

Answer (score 2):

I found the next way.
I placed the DataGrid in a **div**, which style **position: relative;**
The DataGrid was given: **position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%;**

After that, I manipulate it through the dimensions of this **div**.

Sample:

```
<div style={{ position: 'relative', width: '500px', height: '300px' }}>
    <DataGrid
        style={{ position: 'absolute', height: '100%', width: '100%' }}
        ...
     />
</div>
```